# java hotswap a library

Tags: java, maven, hotswap, hotswapagent

I am working on a java project with maven, which uses some of my own libraries as dependencies, that are "evolving in paralel".

I am using HotswapAgent to make hot changes while I am debuging but, I don't know if it is possible to make a hotswap from my own libraries, because there are times that I need to make hot changes to any of my own libraries.

I know that I could add the libreries code to the project, but it would be the last resort, because that code is shared by other projects and I would like to keep them as dependencies

i have configured the hotswap-agent.properties file to add the external libraries
extraClasspath=target/classes;/my-lib-project/classes;

The HotswapAgent is working allright in the main project, but it doesn't  work for my own libraries that i added as dependencies with maven.

I don't know if it's possible or if i'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems you are using the hotswap feature of the agent. Thus the agent picks up changed `.class` filles and hotswaps them.

I would try to disable that and instead let your IDE/Debugger do `hot code replace`. That way you don't need to fumble around with the agent configuration that much.